# Good Learning Material on Parallel Extension of .Net 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, parallel-extensions

Can anybody please suggest me some good learning materials on the new Parallel Extensions and its use in .Net 4 except the MSDN one, so that I can learn -

1. parallel programming on .Net 4
2. the basic differences between non-parallel and parallel programming paradigms
3. how to create data-structures that supports parallel computation?

Any free downloadable material would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck - Joe Albahari has made the [PFX part of C# 4 in a Nutshell](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) public on his website. It's very well written.

You should also read the [PFX team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam) which has a lot of great material.

Comment: +1 for Joe Albaharis' page - thick with content and very well explained.